# Swift DSL - How to Create a Flat Dictionary Out of Known Constant Data?

Tags: ios, swift, dsl

We need to send analytics data to the server. It's conceptually hierarchical. This might be a Swift DSL (Domain Specific Language) question.

An example method call we want to support is:

`trackEvent(name: UCL.tapSaveCar, groupData: UCL.SRP.Results.VehicleModule)`

The `groupData` is the focus of this question.

As part of its processing, `trackEvent` would create a flat dictionary out of this `UCL.SRP.Results.VehicleModule` which looks like this:

`["Group": "UCL", "SubGroup" : "SRP", "Page" : "UCL SRP Results", "Location" : "UCL SRP Results : Vehicle Module", "Value" : ""]`

**Note**: The dictionary key/value of  `"Location" : "UCL SRP Results : Vehicle Module"` is not a typo.

The strangle duplication in the dictionary values is due to the business needs and the tool they use.

Other possible `groupData` that would be transformed would be:

- `UCL.VDP.Enhanced.ActionRow`
- `UCL.DealerMicrosite.Enhanced.ActionRow`
- `UCL.DealerMicrosite.UCLDealerMicrosite.DealerProfile.Waze` Waze puts a `"Value" : "Waze"` into the dictionary.

As you can tell, there's a conceptual hierarchy of **Group.SubGroup.Page.Location.Value**

**Question:** How can one create such a thing that changes known static/constant hierarchical data into flat dictionaries?

**Update**:

- Variations around UCL.SRP.Results.VehicleModule with parenthesis, cased differently, or whatever would be fine too.
- Compile time checking must be supported.
- Analytics SDK requires a dictionary as the type.

Comment: Thanks for asking @JoakimDanielson  The dictionary key/value of  `"Location" : "UCL SRP Results : Vehicle Module"` is not a typo. I clarified / changed the question.

Comment: I am wondering if the following general idea might work:

1) DSL Builder creates struct.
2) struct is encoded into dictionary

Comment: Why not assemble strings and pass them, eg `groupData: "UCL.SRP.Results.VehicleModule"`? Now the task is trivial.

Comment: Or look into `@dynamicMemberLookup` maybe.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate those thoughts @matt. Ideally, compile time checking and code completion would be supported with a non-string effort though. `@dynamicMemberLookup` is awesome and powerful. However, it doesn't provide compile time checking.

Comment: Ok so an array of constants? Eg struct static let, or enum cases?

Comment: possibly. Could be a combination of struct and enums @matt  A DSL Builder might be a class that creates the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can tell, there's a conceptual hierarchy of Group.SubGroup.Page.Location.Value

That looks like a `Tuple` to me. You've always got the same list of elements, right? Dictionaries are great when you have a number of arbitrary key-value pairs, but if the keys are always the same (e.g. group, subgroup, page, etc.) then you should consider a tuple. And since the values are apparently all known also, it might make sense to use enumerations. Here's an example (with some extra made-up values):

```
enum Group {
    case UCL, LCL, LCP, DDO
}

enum Subgroup {
    case SRP, VDP, DealerMicrosite
}

enum Location {
    case DealerProfile, ActionRow, VehicleModule
}

typealias GroupData = (group: Group, 
                       subgroup: Subgroup,
                       page: String,
                       location: Location,
                       value = String)
```

I used `String` here for the page and value components because it's not clear that they're as well-defined. Page seems to be made up of group, subgroup, and a third part; if that third part is enumerable, then you could certainly use an enumeration for that. Same for value, of course.

Once you have that defined, then it shouldn't be a big deal to write functions that convert between `Group.SubGroup.Page.Location.Value` format and `GroupData`.

If tuples don't make sense for your case, e.g. if you want an accessor that returns a `Page` rather than using a separate function, then write a class that contains the same values. Either way, using enumerations for the known parts will let the compiler check that you're always using valid names.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Caleb  The reason a dictionary was specified in the original post is because the analytics SDK requires a dictionary as the type. I love the thoughts shared in here. I agree with this completely: "enumerations for the known parts will let the compiler check that you're always using valid names"